# For which value(s) of parameter m is there a solution for this system

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Imagine a system with one parameter $m$:

\begin{cases}
mx + y = m\\
mx + 2y = 1\\
2x + my = m + 1
\end{cases}

Now the question is: when does this system of equations have a solution?

I know how to do it with the Gaussian method, but how can I do this without the Gaussian method, let's say with **Cramer's rule**?

Comment: Careful: Cramer's rule doesn't tell you much when the system has more than one solution.

Comment: @DylanMoreland So the only way will be to use the method of Gauss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compute the values of $x$ and $y$ dependent on $m$ for the following system, then solve $2x + my = m + 1$ (the last equation) to find the values of parameter $m$ for $x$ and $y$:

\begin{cases}
mx + y = m\\
mx + 2y = 1\\
\end{cases}

So,

\begin{cases}
2mx + 2y =2 m\\ 
mx + 2y = 1\\
\end{cases}

Subtracting two equations, will have:

$$mx=2m-1$$

- If $m \neq 0$, we may divide by $m$ and get $x = (2m-1)/m$ and $y =
     1-m$.
- If $m = 0$, the system has no solution.

Putting $x$ and $y$ in the last equation ($m\neq 0$), we'll have:

$$m^3-3m+2=0 $$

$$(m^3-1)-3m+3=0$$
$$(m-1)(m^2+m+1)-3(m-1)=0$$
$$(m-1)(m^2+m-2)=0$$

Thus the values of parameter $m$ are  $m=1$ or $m=-2$.

Comment: Be careful: If $m = 0$ then the equation $mx = 2m - 1$ gives you $0 = -1$, so you have no solution. Ruling out this case you have $x = \frac{2m - 1}{m}$ or $(2m-1)/m$ which is not th esame as $2m - 1/m$.

Comment: @t.b.: Edited, thank you.

Comment: Looks good now!